# How does Tomcat set its executable file as a Windows service?

Tags: windows, tomcat, windows-services, batch-file

Firstly, I am not at all familiar with Windows batch file programing. Recently I am curious about how [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) sets itself as a Windows service using a batch file. I downloaded the **service.bat** file from Tomcat 6. However, I still don't understand some part of it.

I guess this is the line that the batch actually register the EXE file to the OS, is it right? Is there any syntax explanation?

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% --StartClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams start --StopParams stop
```

And is this used to remove the service?

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" //DS//%SERVICE_NAME%
```

And this is the setting of the parameters?

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% --JvmOptions "-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%;-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%;-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed" --StartMode jvm --StopMode jvm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IS - Install Service
>
> DS - Delete Service
>
> US - Update Service

If you want to create your own services in a batch file look into using `sc.exe` instead.  Run it by itself on a command line for help.

The executable you install as a windows service must be implemented as a windows service.  If it isn't, you need some wrapper that is an official windows service and runs the target exe.  Some commercial examples:

http://www.eltima.com/products/application-as-service/

http://www.firedaemon.com/

I'm surprised I didn't find an open-source/free option.  This type of thing could be done in C# in less than 50 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks, it works in adding the .exe file into the list of windows service. However, I cannot run it. The exception "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion" pops up. Do you happen to know the solution. I am currently googling for it too.

Comment: @Wing C. Chen, oh, the exe must be a windows service.  There are some 3rd party options that provide a windows service which is just a wrapper for other exe's.  http://www.firedaemon.com/ or http://www.eltima.com/products/application-as-service/